# validity of visas electronically

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, canada, visa-expiration

Do airlines or immigration officers verify the validity of visas(forged or real one) electronically when we are travelling from an african country to Schengen area, Canada or USA?

Comment: Why are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

The US, Canada and several Schengen countries require passenger information be sent prior to departure so the answer is, yes, they *can* verify your Passport and Visa.

Whether they do is entirely up to them.

Seems Emirates has the most current list of countries that require this.  It's generally called APIS ([Advance Passenger Information System](https://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/193410/What-is-Advance-Passenger-Information-Why-do-I-need-to-provide-it)).