# Do 'immigration officer at the departure point' check visa validity(real or fake) electronically?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, canada, africa

When we are travelling from an African country to Schengen Area, USA  or Canada, Do 'immigration officer at the departure point' check visa validity(real or fake) electronically?

Comment: I'd say it's exactly _not_ a duplicate, because it's asking about emigration, not airlines. (Emigration, not immigration).

Comment: Why are you concerned about this? Do you have some reason to suspect your visa isn't genuine?

Comment: This is the exact same question as https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125836/validity-of-visas-electronically/125837#125837

Answer (score 0):

That would most likely only happen in countries that don't want their citizens to leave. For example, the USA doesn't care much if you leave the country without a valid visa (they may care if you leave while being accused of a serious crime, but for that they would check your identity, not your visa).

The ones who *do* care are the airlines. That's because if you fly from country A to country B without a required visa, country B will send you right back to country A, at the expense of the airline, and the airline will likely be fined. Obviously the airline doesn't like that at all, so the airline will check that everything is Ok.

Comment: I don't disagree with this answer, but from what I've read on this site it appears that there are indeed some countries that do check destination visas.